# scapy: get DNSQR / DNSRR field values in symbolic/string form

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I'm trying to decode DNS traffic and print query/response data and I'm using python/scapy to decode the packets.

A code snippet:

```
def dns_sniff_v2(pkt):
    if IP in pkt:
        if pkt.haslayer(DNS):
            dns = pkt.getlayer(DNS)
            pkt_time = pkt.sprintf('%sent.time%')

            if pkt.haslayer(DNSQR):
                qr = pkt.getlayer(DNSQR) # DNS query
                values = [ pkt_time, str(ip_src), str(ip_dst), str(dns.id), str(qr.qname), str(qr.qtype), str(qr.qclass) ]

            print "|".join(values)

sniff(iface="eth0", filter="port 53", prn=dns_sniff_v2, store=0)
```

The problem is that `qr.qtype` or `qr.qclass` is getting me the enum's internal int representation (1) instead of the symbolic string value ("A", or "IN"). The same applies to the DNSRR section of response packets.

How can I get a DNSQR or DNSRR field in the symbolic form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the symbolic string value of `qr.qtype` and of `qr.qclass` by invoking the following:

```
qr.get_field('qtype').i2repr(qr, qr.qtype)
qr.get_field('qclass').i2repr(qr, qr.qclass)
```

---

Note that rather than invoking `qr.get_field('qtype')` and `qr.get_field('qclass')` over and over again, you can invoke it once in advance:

```
qtype_field = qr.get_field('qtype')
qclass_field = qr.get_field('qclass')
...
qtype_field.i2repr(qr, qr.qtype)
qclass_field.i2repr(qr, qr.qclass)
```